# should I say that or their? "so that it matches their client’s objectives" or "so that it matches that client's objectives"

Tags: word-choice

Should I say, as part of a sentence, "so that it matches their client’s objectives", or should I say "so that it matches that client's objectives"? Thank you.

Comment: If you refer to ***their** client*, the context must have already clearly identified who ***they*** are (but they might have many clients, and it's possible you neither know nor care which particular one of their clients has objectives that must be met). If you refer to ***that** client*, you must have already indicated *which client you're talking about* (and there may be no third party ***they*** involved at all).

Comment: Who's writing to whom about what?

Comment: This is a sentence from a job description in draft stage....the full sentence is "The PM [portfolio manager] will regularly review and update each client’s portfolio so that it matches their client’s objectives". or alternatively, "The PM [portfolio manager] will regularly review and update each client’s portfolio so that it matches that client’s objectives."

Comment: thanks in advance for ideas on the proper (and clearest) way to say this...

Comment: Your second option is best, as the answer says.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option: *their client's objectives* leaves a question mark over whether the PM is managing a single client (at a time) or multiple clients.

In the latter case, the phrase would be *their clients' objectives*, implying that there might be different (possibly simultaneous) clients with different objectives.

You avoid this difficulty by using *that client's objectives*, where *that client" refers back to *each client*. The question of multiple clients doesn't arise.

Alternatively, you could simply speak of *the client's objectives*, again referring back to each client.

My preference would be for *that* or *the*.